# Error with floating point / scientific notation values in bash

Tags: linux, arrays, bash, floating-point

I have a problem with the following piece of code

```
THRESH_SERIE=("1" "5E-1" "1E-1" "5E-2" "1E-2" "5E-3" "1E-3" "5E-4" "1E-4") 

for ((i=0;i<${#THRESH_SERIE[@]};i++))
do

    let thresh=$(echo ${THRESH_SERIE[$i]})
    $EXEC 1 $N ${thresh} 0 0 >> $OUTPUT
done
```

If I try to run the script it will return an error like the following for each value in the array:

```
/bench_new.sh: line 40: let: thresh=5E: value too great for base (error token is "5E")
```

I've tried also to use floating point numbers (like "0.1"), but it gives a different error. How can I solve this?

Comment: Why don't you just do `thresh=${THRESH_SERIE[$i]}` ?

Comment: Thanks! It worked and it was a really stupid error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No particular reason for the array here (other than they're "fun" to play with):

```
THRESH_SERIE="1 5E-1 1E-1 5E-2 1E-2 5E-3 1E-3 5E-4 1E-4" 

for thresh in ${THRESH_SERIE}
do
  $EXEC 1 $N ${thresh} 0 0 >> $OUTPUT
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is borking is that let treats all it's arguments as arithmetic values.

bash [Arithmetic expression](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr) are defined by a set of rules which default to decimal. the E is not a decimal number and hence the error.

as @DiegoBasch suggests try dropping the let so it's not treated as an arithmetic expression.